# Proof: Characteristic polynomial expressed two different ways equals same polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To my understanding characteristic polynomial can be expressed two different ways and when solving eigenvalues and eigenvectors should give same results. These two ways are:

$$ P_A(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I) $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=det(\lambda I -A) $$

So these two polynomials differ from one another by a sign $(-1)^n$.

We could test this with $2\times2$ matrix A: (because it's easy to compute)

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ P_A(\lambda)=(A-\lambda I) $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=det(\begin{bmatrix}a-\lambda & b \\ c & d - \lambda \end{bmatrix})  $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)= (a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc $$
$$ ad + a(-\lambda) + (-\lambda)d + (-\lambda)(-\lambda)-bc $$
$$ \lambda^2 -\lambda(a+d) + ad - bc $$

Now we could do the same with second characteristic polynomial:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=(\lambda I - A) $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=det(\begin{bmatrix} \lambda - a & -b \\ -c & \lambda - d \end{bmatrix} $$
$$P_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-a)(\lambda-d)-(-b)(-c) $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=\lambda\lambda+\lambda(-d)+(-a)\lambda + (-a)(-d)-(-b)(-c) $$
$$ P_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\lambda(a+d)+ad-bc$$

Now the problem is that this proof applies on 2x2 matrix but how about higher dimensions ? How do you prove this works in higher dimensions as well ? Does such situation exist when these would produce different results ?

If someone could provide some insight on this that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: You forgot to negate the off-diagonal entries. ;-) It is $\lambda I-A$, so all entries of $A$ have to multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: To prove it in general, use the fact that $\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$.

Comment: @Tuki: Have you seen Samuelson's Formula for the Characteristic Polynomial: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html? Look at the 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, ...

Comment: @Moo no i am not aware of this. Thanks for providing this !

Comment: @amsmath i corrected this error on the post and this does not alter the outcome.

Comment: $\det(\lambda I_n-A) = \det(-(A-\lambda I_n)) = (-1)^n\det(A-\lambda I_n)$. So, one of those is always $(-1)^n$ times the other, where $n$ denotes the dimension.